# How to add hostnames for EC2 instances running COUCHBASE 2.1.1 community AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

How to add hostnames for EC2 instances running COUCHBASE 2.1.1 community AMI?

Can someone tell me a step by step approach... The documentation on couchbase site is not helpful ..

it says  "  To configure Couchbase Server instances in the cloud to use hostnames, follow the steps later in this section" .. What steps is it talking about ..

Answer (score 2):

On ec2 each vm is assigned a hostname but the ip address can change when you stop and start the vm instance.  During the couchbase install the couchbase server is set to ip address by default.  You can change this either with the gui or via cmd line with curl.

```
curl -v -X POST -u Administrator:password \
http://127.0.0.1:8091/node/controller/rename \
-d hostname=cb01.yourdomain.com
```

Execute this on each vm and replace `cb01.yourdomain.com` with your assigned hostname.

You could avoid this renaming by initializing the server with hostname in the first place:

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli node-init \
-c cb01.yourdomain.com:8091
```

Answer (score 0):

More info can be found here in the Couchbase Manual.

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#couchbase-getting-started-hostnames